# Configure different PHP-FPM pools based on REQUEST_URI?

Tags: apache-httpd, php

Have a site that is handling all requests through /index.php, and I want to send most requests to a HAproxy balanced pool of PHP-FPM backends, but certain URIs I want to send to a single dedicated pool separately. The URI /admin will be sent to /index.php/admin, etc.

I want to specifically send /api and /admin to a separate pool, while everything else goes to the balanced pool.

I have tried the following, but the REQUEST_URI line only ever matches if I give it an actual existing file (i.e. I can match to /test.php if it is a real file on the filesystem and I request that URI) rather than being able to match locations that would be sent to index.php - I've tried both using =~ regex and == string matching, and this is set in the virtual host not .htaccess. The Else section always runs instead of the If

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
  <If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/admin'">
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000/"
  </If>
  <Else>
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:8000/"
  </Else>
</FilesMatch>
```

REQUEST_URI that is passed into PHP looks correct (i.e., if the path requested is /admin, then /index.php/admin is called and I can see REQUEST_URI in the PHP _SERVER array being /admin), but is it possibly not truly correct at this point in FilesMatch?

I originally tried using SetHandler inside of Location but that doesn't seem to work, or at least FilesMatch overrides it. Can't use Files(Match) inside of Location either...

**edit:**

I found  that ProxyPass works inside Location(Match), so I was able to use ProxyPass instead of SetHandler like so:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:8000/"
</FilesMatch>
<LocationMatch "/admin">
  ProxyPass fcgi://localhost:9000/var/www/index.php/
</LocationMatch>
```

However, I would still like to know why the original method I tried didn't work. Does REQUEST_URI not actually exist at that point, or contains something else, or ... ?

Comment: I think it could be `If` vs `SetEnvIf`, look into it.